# jQuery Calculations with with objects and arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, math

I am trying to calculate annual returns for different economic scenarios.

I have an object with 3 assets in it, each a key-value pair with asset id and asset percentAllocation (weight), like so:

```
percentAllocations = {Asset1 : '26.7', Asset2 : '30.9', Asset3 : '42.5'}
```

I also have an array that contains 3 arrays return values. Each sub-array has return values for 8 different scenarios, like so:

```
assetReturns = [[13.13, 4, -12.23, -23.55, 4.13, -2.3, 18.9, -12.43], [12.12, 4.07, -15.56, -22.98, 4.2, -2.29, 18.92, -12.43],[ 12.12, 4.11, -15.77, -23, 4.05, -2.31, 18.85, -12.34]]
```

What I need to do is for each scenario, multiply the weight of the each asset by the return of the same corresponding asset, and add them all together. To be clearer:

```
Asset1weight*Asset1return + Asset2weight*Asset2return + Asset3weight*Asset3return
```

...for each of the 8 scenarios. In the end, I will want an array or something of 8 values.

I have been trying every combination of $.each and for loop that I can think of and just can't seem to get it. Here's what I have so far, which is doing SOME good things, but is not quite right...

```
//for each asset in the percentAllocations(weights) object
$.each(weights, function(id, weight){  

    //for each scenario        
    for(i=0; i<numberScenarios; i++){//8 scenarios
        //make a placeholder variable
        var temp=0;
        //for each asset
        for(j=0; j<numberFunds; j++){//3 assets

            //multiply the weight of the asset by the return of the asset for that particular scenario
            //add it it to temp
            //is this what is happening? no.
            temp += parseFloat((weight/100)*assetReturns[j][i]);
            console.log("weight of "+id+" x assetReturns["+j+"]["+i+"]= "+temp);

        }
        console.log(temp);
    }

});
```

Any hints you could give me would be greatly appreciated! Even if someone could explain why what I'm doing isn't working... I've pretty much hit a wall with this.  Thank you!

Comment: Your percentAllocations object is syntactically wrong: you should use colons instead of equals

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I just copied it out of the firebug console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through your assets twice, it seems. In pseudo-code:

```
go through every asset;
for each of those assets:
    go through all possible scenarios;
    for each scenario: 
        go through each asset
        for each asset:
            add value to sum
```

To fix this, I think you should first rethink your data-storage, then the function will be easy. I would recommend something like:

```
function Asset(name, allocation, returns) {
    this.name=name;
    this.allocation=allocation;
    this.returns=returns;

    this.value = function(scenario) {
        return this.weight * this.returns[scenario];
    }
}
// same assets you had, structured differently
var assets = [
    new Asset('Asset1', 26.7, [13.13, 4, -12.23, -23.55, 4.13, -2.3, 18.9, -12.43]),
    new Asset('Asset2', 30.9, [12.12, 4.07, -15.56, -22.98, 4.2, -2.29, 18.92, -12.43],
    new Asset('Asset3', 42.5, [ 12.12, 4.11, -15.77, -23, 4.05, -2.31, 18.85, -12.34]
];
var number_of_scenarios = 8; // not ideal, but when you create returns should be set, not here
var total_returns = [];
for(var i = 0; i < number_of_scenarios; i++) {
    var ret = 0;
    $.each(assets, function(id, assset) {
        // this could be done with a normal for loop too
        ret += asset.value(i);
    }
    total_returns.push(ret);
}
console.log(total_returns);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

OK , You could do it like this :

```
var percentAllocations = {Asset1 : '26.7', Asset2 : '30.9', Asset3 :'42.5'};
var assetReturns = [[13.13, 4, -12.23, -23.55, 4.13, -2.3, 18.9, -12.43], [12.12, 4.07, -15.56, -22.98, 4.2, -2.29, 18.92, -12.43],[ 12.12, 4.11, -15.77, -23, 4.05, -2.31, 18.85, -12.34]];
alert(JSON.stringify(percentAllocations));  
alert(assetReturns);

//for each asset in the percentAllocations(weights) object
$.each(percentAllocations, function(id, weight){  
    console.log(id);
    console.log(weight);
    //for each scenario  in assetReturns
    $.each(assetReturns,function(i,value){
        //Gives single scenario like [13.13, 4, -12.23, -23.55, 4.13, -2.3, 18.9, -12.43]
        var temp=0;
        console.log(value);
        $.each(value,function(i,singleScenarioValue){
            //single value obtained from assetReturns : single scenario 
            temp += parseFloat((weight/100)*singleScenarioValue);
        });
                console.log(temp);

    });
});
```

I couldn't figure out the cause of problem from your question. But there are few things that you should check

- The percentAllocations definition is all wrong it should be

> ```
>    percentAllocations = {Asset1 : '26.7', Asset2 : '30.9', Asset3 : '42.5'}
> ```

- Another one is , what is `weights` in the first `foreach` lopp

And here is the Demo [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNGn2/) check the console log for verification.